# Buttons need to update and display based on $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is a questionnaire application.
I have a directive which is a series of buttons which are used to make a choice on a question.  Each question is a JSON object with the score of the selection.  I would like to have the button which corresponds to the selected score to be highlighted, and for the click of a non-selected button to change the score.

I have not yet written the updateQuestion() in the controller, because I need to get my head around how to get them to talk in the Angular way first.

The directive of buttons

```
giftsAppsModule.directive('questionChoice',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template :'<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(5)">Love It</button>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(3)">Enjoy It</button>'+
        '<button class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(2)">Maybe</button>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(1)">Probably not</button>'+
        '<button class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(0)">No way!</button></div>'
}
```

The questions

```
    questionlist= [
    {"index": 1, "question": "Rejoice in God's provision even when the checkbook is in the red.", "gift": "FTH", "score": null},
    {"index": 2, "question": "Clean the kitchen once a week.", "gift": "SVC", "score": null},
    {"index": 3, "question": "Build sets for a drama.", "gift": "CFT", "score": null},
    {"index": 4, "question": "Search the Bible to check the validity of a sermon or Bible lesson.", "gift": "DSC", "score": null}]}
```

The relevant html

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questionlist">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
      <p>{{question.index}}. {{question.question}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      <question-choice></question-choice>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to associate the question with the response, so you can let the directive to create an isolated scope in order to pass the model in. (Without creating the isolated scope, you can access the model inside the directive, but the the directive will lost its reusability. So it is better to make it self-contained.)

```
App.directive('questionChoice', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">' +
            '<button ng-class="{\'button-hl\':ngModel.score == 5}" class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(ngModel, 5)">Love It</button>' +
            '<button ng-class="{\'button-hl\':ngModel.score == 3}" class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(ngModel, 3)">Enjoy It</button>' +
            '<button ng-class="{\'button-hl\':ngModel.score == 2}" class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(ngModel, 2)">Maybe</button>' +
            '<button ng-class="{\'button-hl\':ngModel.score == 1}" class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(ngModel, 1)">Probably not</button>' +
            '<button ng-class="{\'button-hl\':ngModel.score == 0}" class="btn btn-block" ng-click="updateQuestion(ngModel, 0)">No way!</button></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.updateQuestion = function (question, v) {
                question.score = v;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

For the button highlighting, you can use `ng-class` logic to implement. Please take a look at the demo.

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XRTdC/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: OK, I get the concept, but I don't see how I would update the score in the appropriate question...and further...how, once the score is in the model, I can update the button so I can see that it has been selected (say adding a class to turn it green).  Is the scope that is passed in only the indexed question object?

Comment: @DougJohnson-Cookloose I updated the demo and you can see the score will be assigned when you click on any button.

Comment: Got it. And while you're on a roll, do you know how to make the appropriate button change based on the value of the score (not just because of the click...it's possible that the score value could come in with the data).

Comment: @DougJohnson-Cookloose You should post it along with your question. Comments are not used for answers.

Comment: In the question I did ask for the button to be highlighted for the selected score and for the button to be able change the score. You've explained the second part; I was wondering if you had an idea for the first.

Comment: @DougJohnson-Cookloose But how do you want it to be highlighted for a button? Do you have any css created by yourself?

Comment: The highlighting method isn't the issue, I know how to do the CSS. How do I update the button to match the score (button "love it"=5 to highlight when the question.score=5). Class gets added? Attribute gets updated? how? Sorry.

Comment: @DougJohnson-Cookloose Updated the demo. Please check.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. That makes sense to me now.